# STS Gradle tooling refers to outdated version of build.gradle file

Tags: gradle, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, spring-tool-suite

Eclipse's Gradle support seems to be referring to an older version of my build.gradle file. I keep seeing error messages that complain about problems that I already fixed, and the line numbers are off, too. The error messages appear spontaneously, apparently when the Gradle tooling is trying to update or check the Gradle classpath.
For that same gradle file, I also cannot launch a manual build. When I select, Run As... > Gradle Build..., type a task like "build", and then run the build it complains that no tasks were selected. Also, when I try to modify the gradle launch configuration the Apply button always stays disabled, and I cannot modify the launch configuration.

Has anyone seen this? Is there a work-around? Closing and re-opening the project did not help unfortunately, neither did Project > Clean...

Any hints are appreciated :-)

(I'm running Eclipse 4.4.2 with STS 3.6.3 on 64-bit Windows 7 SP 1.)

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding the gradle model that the ide maintains internally by using context menu: Right click on project "Gradle >> Refresh All".